# Is there a characterization for the finite sequences of natural numbers which are the shifts of a permutation?

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

Given a natural number $k<n$ and a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$, I will call $k$ a *shift* of $\sigma$ if there is some $m$ with $\sigma(m)-m\equiv k \mod n$. If one is given a sequence $s=(x_1,...,x_n)$ of $n$ natural numbers between $0$ and $n-1$, is there some known way to determine whether $s$ represents the shifts of some permutatuon in $S_n$? If not, I am also interested in relevant heuristics. Thank you.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h85076p494833

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: that link characterizes sequences which are sums (equivalently, differences) of two permutations. But the question here is slightly different, because here one of the permutations is assumed to be the identity. Does the same result still apply?

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes; if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are two permutations with prescribed differences, then $\sigma\tau^{-1}$ is a permutation with the same multiset of shifts.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: yes, but it was unclear to me whether the question was about multisets of shifts or sequences of shifts.

Comment: @SamHopkins Well, for a sequence it is rather trivial, isn’t it? The characterization is ‘$x_i+i$ are pairwise distinct module $n$’...

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: ah of course, I see.